# Power USB devices separately?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, power

I wonder if it's possible to connect 2 power supplies to one Raspberry Pi 3. One used my Pi itself (GPU/CPU/etc) and other to power USB devices such as USB web camera and USB high-gain WiFi.

This is one scenario, other is running Pi 3 with 7 inch official screen and some USB components.

Either way, I'm seeing that Pi is running at power-saving mode and I would like to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

"I wonder if it's possible to connect 2 power supplies to one Raspberry Pi 3" **NO**

"power USB devices such as USB web camera and USB high-gain WiFi" use a powered hub.